# TryUpdateModelAsync: Is it possible to update specific properties?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

Currently, when I use `TryUpdateModelAsync`, it always returns false because its navigation property `Studio`  is not in `ModelState`.

Is it possible to only update for example `LastName` property?

```cs
    public class Director
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public Studio? Studio { get; set; }
    }

var directorToUpdate = await _context.Director
.Include(i => i.Studio) 
.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);

if (await TryUpdateModelAsync<Director>(
    directorToUpdate,
    "Director",   // Prefix for form value.
    s => s.LastName)) {}
```